# ECR restrict the batch-batch-delete image permission to specific tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I want to allow the user to perform the batchDeleteImage action on ECR repository image only with the image with tag "latest". Is there any way to do so?
I guess ECR IAM policy only supports this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:xxxxxxx:Xxxxxxxxx:repository/repo-name"
}
    ]
}
```

I saw the condition keys that can be used for the ECR but it seems to be for the metadata tags rather than the image tag